# MySQL/PHP: How to do Subscriptions/Joining

Tags: php, mysql

In my app a user can create an event and with those events a specified number of people can join.

The best way I can think of is to have columns named something like joined1, joined2, joined3 .. and so on and input the ID number of the user that joined in that column.

My question is how can I input the user ID into a joined spot that is not taken? The number of the joined spot isn't important but having access to the User IDs are.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: When you're faced with a many to many relation you usually want to have a join table, in this case to add people to events. So you would have a event_user table with (at least) the columns event_id and user_id. This way when you query an event you can join in the users via the join table.

Comment: you need another table for those who have joined (user_id and event_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting to get into some of the more complex aspects of relational data. Ultimately, you'll need to store User/Event subscriptions in a third table, often called a "Lookup" or "Join" table, or a "ManyToMany" relationship.

Considering the following data-set:

```
USER table
id | name
---------
2  | bob
3  | alice

EVENT table
id | creator_id | name
-------------------
9  | 2          | party
```

You'll want to create a THIRD table, storing who is going to the **party**:

```
EVENT_USERS table
event_id | user_id
------------------
9        | 2
9        | 3
```

This is called a ManyToMany relationship, and comes with many complexities, including how to prevent duplication (define a UNIQUE INDEX which includes both event_id and user_id in the INDEX), and how to retrieve the right data (more complex JOINs).

Example JOIN to retrieve who's going:

```
SELECT host.name, e.name, guest.name 
FROM user host
LEFT JOIN event e 
    ON host.id = e.creator_id
LEFT JOIN event_users eu
    ON eu.event_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN user guest
    ON guest.id = eu.user_id

RESULT:
host.name | e.name | guest.name
-------------------------------
bob       | party  | alice
bob       | party  | bob
```

Comment: just do all his homework for him why dont you :-)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks everyone! I was having trouble with everything because the events are set to automatically delete but this fixes that.